# Get data from child components to deliver an event in the parent component

Tags: angular

I need help on the following problem.

I have a parent component that has n children components.

For example:

Parent Component:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    Form1
    <app-form-card></app-form-card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    Form2
    <app-form-card></app-form-card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    Form3
    <app-form-card></app-form-card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    Form4
    <app-form-card></app-form-card>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Child Component:

```
<div class="row mb-5">
  <form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <div class="col-12 mb-2">
    <input type="text" formControlName="user" placeholder="user" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 mb-2">
    <input type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="password" />
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I need to know which is the best way (optimization, maintainability, scalability, good practice) to get all the data of all the forms by clicking the submit button.

I can currently do it in 2 ways.

1 - Get reference of the children with ViewChildren. With this I have access to all the data and functions.

2 - Use Behaivor Subject to send the forms.

I want to know which is the most optimal?

**Update 1**

A posible solution based on the response of user **ccamac**

**Parent Component**

```
  myGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder ) {
    this.myGroup = this.fb.group({
      formArray: this.fb.array([
        new FormGroup({
          user: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          pass: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        }),
          new FormGroup({
          user: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          pass: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        })
      ])
    });
  }
```

**Html of the Parent Component**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myGroup" >
<div formArrayName="formArray">
  <div *ngFor="let item of myGroup.controls?.formArray?.controls; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" formControlName="user">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="pass">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!myGroup.valid">
  Submit
</button>
</form>
```

With this solution don't need a child component.

This solution is good because is maintainable and scalable.

Comment: Have you considered implementing `ControlValueAccessor` in the child components?

Comment: for optimisation, maintainability and scalability I would consider creating a `Service` since they're all separate components or as mentioned already use the `ControlValueAccessor` interface.

Comment: @jpavel I have found the solution by Forms Array. It is simple, maintainable and scalable. Above I explain. I was trying for ControlValueAccessor but it was a bit complicated with validations for more than 1 input. Can you help me with a proposal?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great opportunity to use the FormArray shown here https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

The idea of a FormArray is that it holds an array of FormGroups (or really any AbstractControl).  So it works really well for what you are looking to do, since ultimately you have an array of FormGroups as a collection.  One of the benefits of this approach is that the FormArray still has the many options of a FromGroup including checking all child forms for valid state and getting all errors at once.

Below is a way that this could be built out for your case.

### Parent Component Template

```
<!-- parentFormArray is passed into the child components -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    Form1
    <app-form-card [parentFormArray]="form"></app-form-card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    Form2
    <app-form-card [parentFormArray]="form"></app-form-card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    Form3
    <app-form-card [parentFormArray]="form"></app-form-card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    Form4
    <app-form-card [parentFormArray]="form"></app-form-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Parent Component Class

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    form: FormArray;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form = this.fb.array([]); // start the formArray off as a blank array
    }
```

### Child Component Template (no changes needed here)

```
<div class="row mb-5">
  <form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <div class="col-12 mb-2">
    <input type="text" formControlName="user" placeholder="user" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 mb-2">
    <input type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="password" />
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

### Child Component Class

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() parentFormArray: FormArray; // this was passed in from the parent

    profileForm: FormGroup; // not sure how this is being built out, but I'm sure you are handling it somewhere

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // first do whatever code is needed to build out the profile form
        // then push it onto the parent form array
        this.parentFormArray.push(this.profileForm);
    }
```

Comment: <app-form-card [parentFormArray]="form"></app-form-card> is correct? or     <app-form-card [(parentFormArray)]="form"></app-form-card>. How does the parent component detect any change?

Comment: you are passing in the form object from the parent, so that means you have the form that all of the child forms are being put into.  So you should be able to subscribe to valueChanges event of the form, which is an AbstractControl https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges